# Double Installation of VestaCP

Tags: database, vesta

I installed `Vestaccp` on my `VPS (CentOS 6.9)` and it was working perfectly.
Today, by mistake I installed `VestaCP` again on the same server because I was thinking I was installing on my different `VPS`. Therefore I installed `VestaCP` twice on the server.
As a result, all of my websites running on my `old vestaCP` went down and I'm not even able to get their database dump coz everything is written by new installation.
`New VestaCP` placed files and database of `old vestacp` installation on following locations those I can copy easily but I can't use those databases anymore

**Old VestaCP current path[Files of websites]:**

```
/root/vst_install_backups/1526175423/home/web/
```

**Old VestaCP Database current path:**

```
/root/vst_install_backups/1526175423/mysql/mysql_datadir
```

Currently I can't even get database dump of my `old vestacp` because of new installation. 
Please guide me how can I database dump of my old working websites so I can use them to rum my websites back.
Looking for kind response.